# React app displaying javascript in firefox only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

My react app is displaying what appears to be javascript on the screen in firefox, it does not display in chrome or edge. Below is a screenshot of what i see in firefox.

if i comment out the local stylesheet like this,  it disappears.

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" /> -->
```

Any one have anyideas as to why this may be?

[[image: screen capture of behaviour described above1]

when i inspect it shows as part of the head tag in html:

[image: screen capture of dom with that wlwmwnt highlighted]

index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="portal"></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: that looks like (ancient, despite having many modern functions) javascript, not a header

Comment: thanks for your input, i have updated with some more info based on your suggestions

Comment: It seems you made the head a flex container, somehow. What does the rule panel say for that element?

Comment: Thanks so much that was it. I had put *{display: flex;}. I foved it to body and it has disappeared. Thanks again.